# Running time for an array with elements of different size

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

For example, for the array A[1,...,n], we assume that all the elements are of the same size. Then iterating through the array takes O(n) time. What if the size of the elements is different (still limited)? How does that affect the running time?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that you need to research the meaning of "Big-O" notation.  There are plenty of tutorial pages available on line.  However, I'm not clear on just what you don't understand, partly because you're mixing references to running time and the algorithmic complexity (big-O); they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more precise. I understand that "Big-O" is just a notation used to indicate a bound on the running time

Comment: What do you mean by size? Can you show some example code that exhibits this property?

Comment: It's more of a theoretical question. The size of each of the elements of the array. For example we assume that all the elements of the array will at most be 32-bits long. But what if we change that. Let's say one of the elements is now 1024-bits long, and now all the elements of the array are not of the same size. How does that affect the running time of the algorithm?

Comment: That depends on what *iterating them* means.

Comment: The algorithm I have in mind is the recursive bubble sort algorithm. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-bubble-sort/. The running time of this algorithm is O(n^2). So how does the running time get affected by what I said in the last comment?

Comment: I don't see how the size would affect runtime. Unless the runtime of the comparison depends on the size.

Comment: Yes that's what I was wondering. The runtime of the comparison and the swap is probably affected by the size.

Comment: That can only be examined with a specific example. There are situations when it does and situations when it doesn't.

Comment: Size certainly affects runtime. For example, if the size of an element in the array was 10^2000, the algorithm would have to run longer than the age of the universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great theoretical question. There are three answers.

1. Practically, size of the number almost never affects runtime. In practice, all the numbers in the array are encoded using the same number of bits. If you are using a int32, it will be 32 bits; if a int16, 16 bits; and so on. The number 1 encoded in int32 requires just the same number of bits (32) as the ginormous number 2^31 encoded in int32.
2. Theoretically, size of the number absolutely affects runtime. For example, if the size of an element in the array was 10^2000, any algorithm acting on this array would have to run longer than the age of the universe just to read this element.
3. An interesting case study is radix sorting, where size of the number affects runtime and not just theoretically. Radix sorting is a type of sorting algorithm whose runtime is O(nK) where n is the number of elements in the array and K is proportional to the number of bits required to represent each element of the array. So radix sorting an array of int32 objects would require roughly twice as much runtime as radix sorting an array of int16 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't yet described your comparison paradigm, we can't answer for certain.  However, your reference to **bubble sort** suggests that your elements are simple numerical scalar values, being compared with the common definitions of ordering.

The *running time* is generally affected: it can take up to 32 times as long to compare 1024-bit values as 32-bit values.  However, that overhead is merely a constant coefficient: the algorithmic complexity is still **O(N^2)**.  The bubble sort will still complete after `(N)*(N-1)/2` comparisons, each of which has a fixed, finite upper bound.

One simple way to envision this is to pre-process all of the array elements to the size of the largest.  In the numerical case you mentioned, you left-fill every element with zeroes to 1024 bits.  Now all of the elements are the same size, and we've reduced the problem to something that has previously been solved.